# Using barchart on outputs

Tags: plotting, code

I want to use  barchart to make a plot with a series of outputs from the given command

```
max1={max, arg} = NMaximize[{solutionI[t], 0 < t < 100}, t]
```

here it is "arg" that I want to extract, and insert in Barchart:

```
BarChart[{max1[arg],max2[arg],max3[arg],max4[arg],max5[arg]}]
```

But this didn't work. How do I extract arg from max1 for the BarChart code?

Thanks

Comment: Please include a definition for `solutionI[t]`

Comment: Think about following: I want to calculate $x^2$ where $x=2$, I write `arg= x->2; arg^2`, what's wrong?

Comment: As mentioned under your previous questions, usage of `/.` and `->` are something you must understand, please read there documents carefully, don't use them blindly.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
BarChart[{max1[[2]] // Values}]
```

> [image]

And then

```
BarChart@Flatten[Values@#[[2]] & /@ {max1, max2, max3, max4, max5}]
```

---

**Edit**

A more literal answer would be...

```
{max, arg} = NMaximize[{solutionI[t], 0 < t < 100}, t];
max1 = Association[arg -> max] (* <|{t -> 17.1624} -> 1407.08|> *)
max1[arg] (* max1[arg] *)
```

...though I wouldn't suggest this as it is a messy looking `Key`